# How can I find the date code on my battery?

Tags: battery, car

I can't find out what the date of manufacture is the car battery. The battery is Autopart Galaxy Optimal power and its code N5243 ZHL 0146.

Comment: One possibility is week 46 of 2001, but you need to check with whoever stamped it as to their system.

Comment: Is this number heat stamped into the case? Or is it on the sticker? Also, is there a small round sticker on the side anywhere?

Comment: Number is heat stamped into the case and there is no sticker anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The heat stamp is also a date code, as it likely tells the manufacturer which production line and which day, if not time of day, the battery left the line. (This is a relatively safe assumption as most battery factories are registered at least ISO 9001.)

You will need to take that heat stamp to the manufacturer to find out what it is telling you. The retailer should either have this information or can get it very easily from the factory.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a chance that it is week 46 of 2001.

But there is a stronger chance that it is a serial number or the date code has some sort of encryption. Manufactures do this to stop people from modifying the code to make false warranty claims. If this is the case then the only way to find it's age is to speak to the manufacture or retailer but in a lot of cases they won't tell you the actual age just wether it's covered under warranty or not.